# How to change cursor size in Webstorm?

Tags: webstorm

I love to work with Webstorm IDE, but the cursor size is bothering me a lot. Even when I want to highlight a character or a word, I get confused. I tried to see editor properties but this didn't work for me.

So how can I change the size of that cursor or even change it's shape?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Webstorm the cursor is called the caret. This page has information on changing the style of it:

https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/editor-appearance.html

You're going to want to change the setting `Use block caret`, and it can be found in the menu:

```
File | Settings | IDE Settings | Editor - Appearance
```

> Use block caret   --  Select this check box to have the block caret applied in the Insert mode and the usual caret applied in the
>   Overwrite mode.
>   Clear this check box to have the usual caret applied in the Insert mode and the block caret applied in the Overwrite mode.

Comment: And how can I change the cursor for the terminal ?

Comment: Try posting that as a separate question @RoyiNamir.